# How to write a Windows batch script that uses findstr to search a file for a string that contains quotes, spaces, and colon

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, findstr

I'm attempting to write a batch script that searches a file using findstr for the following string:

```
"jobType" : "upgrade_application"
```

Appreciate any assistance.

I've tried several variations of the following:

```
findstr /C:""jobType" : "upgrade_application"" < "Filename"
```

```
findstr /C:"""jobType"" : ""upgrade_application""" < "Filename"
```

Comment: Findstr /C:"\"jobType\" : \"upgrade_application\"" < "filename"

Comment: This worked, thank you! Could you explain how/why it does?

Comment: The backslashes "escape" the quotes, removing their "special character" status.

Comment: Please open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `findstr /?` and read the output help for this [Windows command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/windows-commands). There is no need for an input redirection. There should be used in the batch file `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /C:"\"jobType\" : \"upgrade_application\"" "filename"` without the redirection operator `<` because of __FINDSTR__ can open itself a file. It can even search in all files of a directory or an entire directory tree matching a wildcard pattern.